# How to get current position of the GridView

Tags: android, gridview, position, lazy-loading

first of all I have to excuse for my English
I want to get the position of the user's scroll of the GridView to if user get to the end of the GridView do something 
how can i do that ? should i get the position in the OnScrollListener or in the adapter 
P.S : i use UIL and load images in GridView
I would appreciate your help.